value of another column that is the same row as my last lag value
I have a timeseries dataset. I am looking to make a new column that represents the last reported (not null) value. I think I have this part figured out, using a combination of lag and last
I would also like to know the timestamp for that last reported (non null) value. I never expect timestamp_ms to be null, even though val can be null.
Sample Data
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(timestamp_ms=1672531200000, val='19'),
    Row(timestamp_ms=1672532100000, val='20'),
    Row(timestamp_ms=1672533000000, val=None),
    Row(timestamp_ms=1672533900000, val='22'),
    Row(timestamp_ms=1672534800000, val=None),
    Row(timestamp_ms=1672535700000, val=None),
    Row(timestamp_ms=1672536600000, val='25'),
    Row(timestamp_ms=1672537500000, val='20'),
    Row(timestamp_ms=1672538400000, val='27')
])
df.show()

Sample Code
Returns the Last Lagged Value and attempts to return the timestamp when that value was reported.
df_lag = df.withColumn("lag_prev_val", F.lag("val")\
                                    .over(Window.partitionBy()\
                                    .orderBy("timestamp_ms"))
                         )\
            .withColumn("last_lag_prev_val", F.last("lag_prev_val", True)\
                                    .over(Window.partitionBy()\
                                    .orderBy("timestamp_ms"))
                         )\
            .withColumn("last_lag_prev_time", F.lag("timestamp_ms")\
                                .over(Window.partitionBy()\
                                .orderBy("timestamp_ms"))
                     )
df_lag.show()

Current Output
last_lag_prev_time represents the previously reported timestamp, rather than the timestamp associated with the last_lag_prev_val



timestamp_ms
val
lag_prev_val
last_lag_prev_val
last_lag_prev_time




1672531200000
19
null
null
null


1672532100000
20
19
19
1672531200000


1672533000000
null
20
20
1672532100000


1672533900000
22
null
20
1672533000000


1672534800000
null
22
22
1672533900000


1672535700000
null
null
22
1672534800000


1672536600000
25
null
22
1672535700000


1672537500000
20
25
25
1672536600000


1672538400000
27
20
20
1672537500000



Ideal output
The output I want (bolded the differences) is for the last_lag_prev_time column to represent the timestamp_ms value that is from the same row as the original val that was used to populate `last_lag_prev_val'



timestamp_ms
val
lag_prev_val
last_lag_prev_val
last_lag_prev_time




1672531200000
19
null
null
null


1672532100000
20
19
19
1672531200000


1672533000000
null
20
20
1672532100000


1672533900000
22
null
20
1672532100000


1672534800000
null
22
22
1672533900000


1672535700000
null
null
22
1672533900000


1672536600000
25
null
22
1672533900000


1672537500000
20
25
25
1672536600000


1672538400000
27
20
20
1672537500000




One solution would be to only consider timestamps in rows that don't have a val that is NULL, which we can do by creating a column called val_timestamp_ms. Then we can get the last timestamp from this new column and also apply a lag. For example:
df.withColumn("lag_prev_val", F.lag("val")\
                                    .over(Window.partitionBy()\
                                    .orderBy("timestamp_ms"))
                         )\
            .withColumn("last_lag_prev_val", F.last("lag_prev_val", True)\
                                    .over(Window.partitionBy()\
                                    .orderBy("timestamp_ms"))
                         )\
            .withColumn("val_timestamp_ms", F.when(F.col("val").isNull(), None)\
                                .otherwise(F.col("timestamp_ms"))
                         )\
            .withColumn("last_prev_time", F.last("val_timestamp_ms", True)\
                                    .over(Window.partitionBy()\
                                    .orderBy("timestamp_ms"))
                         )\
            .withColumn("last_lag_prev_time", F.lag("last_prev_time")\
                                    .over(Window.partitionBy()\
                                    .orderBy("timestamp_ms"))
                         )

+-------------+----+------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+
| timestamp_ms| val|lag_prev_val|last_lag_prev_val|val_timestamp_ms|last_prev_time|last_lag_prev_time|
+-------------+----+------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+
|1672531200000|  19|        NULL|             NULL|   1672531200000| 1672531200000|              NULL|
|1672532100000|  20|          19|               19|   1672532100000| 1672532100000|     1672531200000|
|1672533000000|NULL|          20|               20|            NULL| 1672532100000|     1672532100000|
|1672533900000|  22|        NULL|               20|   1672533900000| 1672533900000|     1672532100000|
|1672534800000|NULL|          22|               22|            NULL| 1672533900000|     1672533900000|
|1672535700000|NULL|        NULL|               22|            NULL| 1672533900000|     1672533900000|
|1672536600000|  25|        NULL|               22|   1672536600000| 1672536600000|     1672533900000|
|1672537500000|  20|          25|               25|   1672537500000| 1672537500000|     1672536600000|
|1672538400000|  27|          20|               20|   1672538400000| 1672538400000|     1672537500000|
+-------------+----+------------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+


Ahh makes sense, Thank You!

You're welcome – glad to have helped!
